# Badge notifications are inconsistent as to whether I should see my profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

Today I got 5 notifications telling me that I earned the Yearling badge on 5 different sites.

[image: 5 yearling badges]

I got a badge on the following sites: User Experience, User Experience Meta, English Language and Usage, English Language and Usage Meta, and Area 51.

I have a profile on all 5 sites, but there was only a link to my profile on User Experience and English Language and Usage.

These notifications should be consistent, so that there is either a link to my profile on all of them, or on none of them.

Comment: that's a really minor bug. It's a different text ;)

Comment: Likely not insignificant that the ones that didn't include the "See your profile" text are meta sites. As far as bugs go this seems incredibly trivial - perhaps an assumption was made that those who are even somewhat involved on meta sites are more likely to know where to view badges and therefore don't really need a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Silly edge case where the meta sites weren't available at the time we're appending that string, so looking up profiles to link to failed.